# Weird behavior/crashes caused by low usable RAM?

Tags: android, memory

I'm busy developing a 'simple' app for the radio controlled amateur/professional race world. This app contains a lot of static textviews, imageviews, tables etc. To show this information I use a viewpager.  Every new page is a fragment, every fragment got its own static layout. Every fragment contains around 50 views, for example(my post was too long so I put it in a text file so you can download it):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxg8tsutzu6lndw/fragment.txt

My code to handle these fragments looks like this:

```
public class SubScreenHandler extends FragmentActivity{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub_screen_handler_layout);
        ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragmentList.addAll((ArrayList<Fragment>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fragmentList"));
        for (Object item : fragmentList) {
            if (!(item instanceof Fragment)) {
                throw new ClassCastException("List contained non-Fragment objects: " + item.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            }
        }
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragmentList));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        UnderlinePageIndicator underlinePageIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        underlinePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        doFirstRun();
    }

    private void doFirstRun(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("com.example.offroad_set_up_book", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
            editor.commit();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alertDialog_swipe_function));
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
}

class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentList.addAll(fragments);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragmentList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

}
```

The fragmentList contains a number of fragments(like the one above) that are specified in the main activity and then put in the intent.

**Now the problem:**
This application works fine on my LG G3 (3gb of ram), this application work fine in the android emulator it also does fine on my samsung galaxy s3. However on another smartphone (alcatel one touch 995 with 512mb of ram) the application does behave quite weird. First of all not everything is showing correctly on the screen. Like some parts of the table borders are not shown at all. Eventually when I swipe between fragments my application crashes with a nullpointerexception. 
Also I get some weird logging which I don't get on my LG G3 and my galaxy s3:

```
08-05 20:58:43.682    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4b3c3000 size:12165120 offset:10629120 fd:65
08-05 20:58:43.953    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4c1e1000 size:13701120 offset:12165120 fd:68
08-05 20:58:43.983    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4cef2000 size:21626880 offset:20090880 fd:71
08-05 20:58:43.993    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x49b81000 size:6205440 offset:4669440
08-05 20:58:43.993    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4a32c000 size:4669440 offset:3133440
08-05 20:58:43.993    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4a8a0000 size:10629120 offset:9093120
```

Than after some swiping I get my nullpointerexception:

```
08-05 20:59:47.154    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a911f8)
08-05 20:59:47.174    5722-5722/com.example.offroad_set_up_book E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1542)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1572)
            at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1164)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:546)
            at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1113)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1185)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2809)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:124)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1162)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4440)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it has something to do with the memory of the alcatel one touch. However if it is running out of memory, why is the garbage collector never called? The GC is called on my LG G3 and S3 once (also on a friends LG optimus g) at the beginning when the viewpager is created. Also I never receive an outofmemory exception. Anyone maybe knows what is going on here??

NOTE: 
All the phones are running on at least android 4.xxx

Comment: where is your onSavedInstanceState code?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I don't see why I should make use of it?

Comment: When your app goes into the background garbage collection can start free resources from it on low memory.  SavedInstance state is used to insure that if this happens and the activity is brought back to the foreground it can reinstate variables and references so you don't get null pointers.. your all is not crashing because it's out of memory it's crashing because of a null pointer

Comment: Oke so you mean I should save references and variables so the GC won't be able to collect them preventing me to get a nullpointer when I go back to the foreground. What exactly should I save then? Because all the fragments that are not in view to the user are destroyed anyway because of the fragmentStatePagerAdapter. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html. Also do you know what these logs mean:  D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4b3c3000 size:12165120 offset:10629120 fd:65?

Comment: Sort of.. more like so the system can rebuild them.. Google Android developer savedInstanceState and lifecycle

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter and my comment wasn't finished yet :). See above for the full comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The weird crashes were occurring due I'll imported "import android.app.Fragment;" on the main activity (which puts the fragments in the second acitivty) and imported "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;" on the second activity. Everything is working right now!